# Why does the initializer called in such a case?

Tags: python

I have such a layout of my packages:

Under nlu/ dirctory, I have:

nlu/nlup.py

```
class NLUP(object)

   def __init__(self)
      ...

      print("Why is this classed? This initializer is heary!")
```

nlu/**init**.py

```
from nlu import nlup
nls = nlup.NLUP()
...
```

nlu/utils/text_normalizer.py

```
def normalize(text):
    if not text:
        return " "
```

Then, I have a file to test the text normalizer:
tools/test,py:

```
from nlu.utils import text_normalizer

print('why is the initialier of NLUP called?')
```

I don't understand why the import of 'text_normalizer' caused the calling of the NLUP's initilizer. The normalizer.py doesn't import anything from the 'nlu' package. It only uses the namespace: "from nlu.utils".

Is there a way to avoid this? When I call 'normlaize' function, I don't want the initializer of NLUP is called. It's just that text_normalizer is under the package of nlu.

Is this normal?

```
setup.py
setup(name='nlu',
      version='1.0',

      packages=['nlu'],
      package_dir={'nlu':'nlu'},
      package_data={'nlu':['*.*']}
)
```

Comment: Parent packages have to be initialized to load any of their submodules. Initializing `nlu` calls `nlup.NLUP()`.

Comment: This is normal.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, how to avoid this? I want text_normalizer to be under the nlu big package, but when users only call functions in text_normalizer, it won't cause NLUP to be initialized.